# C run time error (Program supposed to print first 1000 prime numbers)

Tags: c, runtime

I have used the isPrime() function in other programs and it works perfectly, I have even referenced it in the same way before. For some reason in this program the function isn't working. I used printf() to check what the function was returning and it seems to be memory locations. I don't know what to change though because, as I said, I am sure the function works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

 int isPrime(int a);
 int result;
 int x = 1;
 while(x <= 1000){

     result = isPrime(x);
     if (result == 1){
        printf("%d\n",x);
    }
    x++;
 }
 }

 int isPrime(int a){

 int count;
 int z;
 if(a == 1){
   return 0;
 } else {

   for (z = a; z != 0; z-- ){
      if(a % z == 0){
         count++;
      }
   }
   if(count <= 2){
      return 1;
   } else {
     return 0;
   }
 }  
}
```

Comment: Maybe add an initial value to count in the function. To z as well. Not sure, but might fix the problem. int count=0; intz=0;

Comment: @Davlumbaz just for count initialization is needed anyways  `z = a` in for loop

Comment: @Koushik Ah right, z is initialized in the loop, missed that. Initializing count = 0; should fix the problem then.

Comment: yeh I changed it to count = 0; and its worked now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize `count` to 0.

Apart from this, on my system it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Move `int isPrime(int a);` out of the `main()` function, up above it. Or put it into a separate header file. Review [function prototypes](http://opencbp.sourceforge.net/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/opencbook/func.prototypes.html) when you have time.

Answer (score 0):

The `count` variable, in your program is a local variable, and hence like all local variables should be initialized before use or it uses a leftover value from the stack, and with such an unpredictable and random value , your program behavior is undefined.